# Remove mismatch and add missing json jq

Tags: json, shell, sed, jq

Hi I have two file for example:

file1.json

```
{
  "id": "001",
  "name" : "my_policy",

  "list_1": ["111111111", "22222222","33333333"],
  "list_2": ["a", "b","c"],
  .....
}
```

Then I have file2.json (not always has the same field as f1)

```
{    
  "list_1": ["111111111","111111122","33333333"],
  "list_2": ["a", "b","c","d","e"],
  .....
}
```

How I can via jq merge same keys  values in the two file json and in addiction to the merge operation remove from file1 keys the values non present in file2 ?
So get this result:

```
{
 "id": "001",
 "policy" : "my_policy",
 "list_1": ["111111111","111111122","33333333"],
 "list_2": ["a", "b","c","d","e"],
  .....
}
```

I solved the merge operation via:

```
jq -s 'reduce .[] as $item ({}; reduce ($item | keys_unsorted[]) as $key (.; $item[$key] as $val | ( $val | type) as $ type | .[$key] = if ( $type == "array") then (.[$key] + $val | unique) elif ($type == "object") then (.[$key] + $val) else $val end ))' file1.json f2.json
```

How I can solve? Or is impossible via jq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite simple once you figure out how to find the difference among two list items and add/unique them. One way would be to

```
jq --slurpfile s 2.json -f script.jq 1.json
```

Where my script contents are

```
#!/usr/bin/env jq -f

# backup list_1, list_2 from 1.json
.list_1 as $l1  |
.list_2 as $l2  |
# Perform the operation of removing file1 keys not present in 2.json
# for both list_1 and list_2
( ( $l1 - ( $l1 - $s[].list_1 ) ) +  $s[].list_1 | unique ) as $f1 |
( ( $l2 - ( $l2 - $s[].list_2 ) ) +  $s[].list_2 | unique ) as $f2 |
# Update the original result 1.json with the modified content
.list_1 |= $f1 |
.list_2 |= $f2
```

or directly from the command line as

```
jq --slurpfile s 2.json '
  .list_1 as $l1  |
  .list_2 as $l2  |
  ( ( $l1 - ( $l1 - $s[].list_1 ) ) +  $s[].list_1 | unique ) as $f1 |
  ( ( $l2 - ( $l2 - $s[].list_2 ) ) +  $s[].list_2 | unique ) as $f2 |
  .list_1 |= $f1 |
  .list_2 |= $f2
' 1.json
```

Comment: Yes that solve everything. Is ti possibile to generalize instead of write list_1, list_2 etc? Or is better if I explicit write all the json key that i need to update?

Comment: @mat656 : Yes you can, but that’s a different question altogether. Please ask a new question for it